# Dynamic HTML IDs (PHP, Java, and a bit of SQL)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a web page which generates a series of unique DIV IDs, each displaying different content based off of the entries in an SQL table.

Each div has a "hide" and "show" button, which work independently when manually giving each div a unique name.

I can get the divs themselves to generate based on class names in PHP, which displays the divs correctly.

The problem lies in the "hide" and "show" buttons since they're controlled by JavaScript. The code is as follows:

```
for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
{
for($i =0; $i < $rows2; $i++)
{   
    if (mysql_num_rows($ans) > 0) //check if widget table is empty
    {   

        $widgetusr[$j] = mysql_result($ans,$j,'wname')or die(mysql_error()); //user's widget
    $widgetstore[$i] = mysql_result($ans2,$i,'wname'); //store widget

    if($widgetusr[$j] == $widgetstore[$i] && $widgetusr[$j] != 'Medieval Calendar') //check if user has already purchased the widget
    {   
        echo "<div class=widget_container".$j%2 .">"; //container divs are named 1 and 0. j mod 2 should return either 1 or 0
        ?>
        <!----Start of weather Widget--->       

        <!---Script for show/hide buttons weather widget--->
           <script>
        var widg = "<?php echo $widgetusr[$j]; ?>";
        var id = "#" + widg;


        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#hide1").click(function(){
           $(id).hide();
         });
        $("#show1").click(function(){
         $(id).show();
         });
        });

        </script>

        <button id="hide1">Hide</button>
        <button id="show1">Show</button>

        <!---End Script for show/hide buttons weather widget--->  
        <?php
          echo "<div class = 'widget' id='$widgetusr[$j]'>
               </div>
        </div>
        <!----End of Widget---> ";          

    }
}
else
{   
        echo "You have no widgets please visit <a href='store.php'> the store </a> to purchase some. <br/>"; //widget table is empty. Redirect to widget store.
}
}
}
?>
```

I tried to pass the php varriable (containing an SQL value) to JavaScript (which works successfully, I was able to print out "#financial widget" as an id name.), however neither the show, nor hide button works. The generated divs all have the correct names also.

If additional information is required please ask. I tried to be as general as possible.

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML instead of the PHP?

Comment: Instead of using `id`s I think it would be a lot easier for you to use classes.

Comment: While I agree with you, each div needs to be independently controlled. Assigning these to classes would make clicking one button activate all the divs with that class.

Comment: You can't use blanks in your id like in "financial widget". Maybe thats the point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really only need one button. Change your php to render the following html

```
<div class="widget_container">
    <button class="btn ">Hide</button> 
    <div class="widget">widget1</div>
</div>
<div class="widget_container">
    <button class="btn">Hide</button> 
    <div class="widget">widget2</div>
</div>   
<div class="widget_container">
    <button class="btn">Hide</button> 
    <div class="widget">widget3</div>
</div>
```

and output the following **Outside** of the loop, ensuring jQuery is loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   //Standar jquery doc ready event, fires when the dom is loaded
   $(document).ready(function(){  
       //add an event listener elements with a class of "btn"
       $('.btn').click(function () {  
          //"this" is the element click, so we find siblings of this with a class
          //of "widget" and toggle its visibility
          $(this).siblings('.widget').toggle();
          //Change the text of the button the below is short hand for:
          //if($(this).text() == "Hide"){
          //    $(this).text("Show");
          //}else{
          //    $(this).text("Hide");
          //}
          $(this).text($(this).text() == "Hide" ? "Show" : "Hide"); 
       });
   });
</script>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bdpm4/)

Some useful links:

- http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/
- http://api.jquery.com/click/
- http://api.jquery.com/siblings/
- http://api.jquery.com/closest/
- http://api.jquery.com/toggle/
- http://api.jquery.com/text/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Example with fixed height widgets: http://jsfiddle.net/bdpm4/2/

**Update 2**
Perhaps a better way to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/bdpm4/3/

Comment: It's hard to say the best way to change the height of the widget container. Is the widget a fixed height? If so just apply a CSS class to `widget` specifying a height and maybe margins as well.

Comment: I had an initial height on the widget container, removing it creates the effect I want. It's not pretty, but it works. Thanks for the resources.!

Answer (score 0):

you should use class instead of id and dont put your `$(document).ready()` in the loop.

HTML:

```
<div class="widget_container">
    <button class="btn hideBtn">Hide</button>
    <button class="btn showBtn">Show</button>    
    <div class="widget">widget1</div>
</div>
<div class="widget_container">
    <button class="btn hideBtn">Hide</button>
    <button class="btn showBtn">Show</button>    
    <div class="widget">widget2</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').on('click', function (evt) {
        var btn = $(evt.target);
        btn.siblings('.widget').toggle();
        btn.parent().find('.btn').toggle();
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.showBtn {
    display:none;
}
```

here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/xdA4r/4/

Comment: Your demo looks like exactly what I'm looking for, however upon applying your solution I get an error saying (evt) is not a function. What package/script is this included in?

Comment: I just use JQuery. `evt` is the `eventObject` send to the handler function (http://api.jquery.com/on/). maybe you made a mistake when copying?

Comment: I copied it character for character, and like I said, the example works correctly, however I copied your code and put it outside the loop like you said, and my firebug console is returning this:

TypeError: $(...).on is not a function
$('.btn').on('click', function (evt) {

Comment: when do you load JQuery ? and which version do you load ?

Comment: Nevermind I updated my jQuery version. (still kinda new at this) I still have an issue with the code however. In the example you provided, the hide and show buttons swap when they are clicked, on mine the hide button disappears and nothing else appears in it's place.

Is there supposed to be additional CSS for .hideBtn?

Comment: all your buttons must have the class `btn`.

Comment: All the buttons have the class btn, do the buttons also have to be outside the loop>

Comment: no your buttons must be in the loop. It should work if you use the same html structure and classname. You can also try Jon P alternative. same thing with only one button.